# My bukkit plugin won't load:Error loading plugin: Directory 'xxx.jar' failed to load

Tags: java, minecraft

Before I imported mirai-core, the plugin worked normally, but now importing it I get an error, I just called the mirai-core API.
This is not likely to be a problem with failed logins QQ, the server just started it failed to load.

This is the log:

```
Starting org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main
*** Warning, you've not updated in a while! ***
*** Please download a new build as per instructions from https://papermc.io/downloads/paper ***
System Info: Java 19 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.1+10-21) Host: Windows 11 10.0 (amd64)
Loading libraries, please wait...
2023-07-04 09:39:37,444 ServerMain WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
[09:39:40 ERROR]: [DirectoryProviderSource] Error loading plugin: Directory 'plugins\QToSer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed to load!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Directory 'plugins\QToSer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed to load!
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:59) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.lambda$registerProviders$1(DirectoryProviderSource.java:34) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1921) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:32) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:14) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.util.EntrypointUtil.registerProvidersFromSource(EntrypointUtil.java:14) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.PluginInitializerManager.load(PluginInitializerManager.java:100) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(Main.java:126) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main.main(Main.java:316) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paperclip.Paperclip.lambda$main$0(Paperclip.java:42) ~[app:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:327) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:760) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:846) ~[?:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProviderFactory.create(SpigotPluginProviderFactory.java:36) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProviderFactory.create(SpigotPluginProviderFactory.java:16) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.PluginFileType.getConfig(PluginFileType.java:77) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.PluginFileType.register(PluginFileType.java:70) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:57) ~[paper-1.20.jar:git-Paper-3]
    ... 20 more
[09:39:49 INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[09:39:52 INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[09:39:53 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.20
[09:39:53 INFO]: Loading properties
[09:39:53 INFO]: This server is running Paper version git-Paper-3 (MC: 1.20) (Implementing API version 1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT) (Git: dc30ee5)
[09:39:53 INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
```

This is code:

```
public final class QToSer extends JavaPlugin implements Listener, CommandExecutor {

    public static void say(String s) {
        CommandSender sender = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();
        sender.sendMessage(s);
    }

    public static ToQ toQ = new ToQ();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new CServerLoad(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new CAsyncPlayerChat(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new CPlayerJoinEvent(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("send").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender sender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String label, String[] args) {
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("send")) {
            if (!(sender.isOp() || sender.hasPermission("group.vip") || sender.hasPermission("group.lv8"))){
                sender.sendMessage("你没有权限让机器人自愿发话");
                return true;
            }
            try {
                toQ.bot.getGroup(*********).sendMessage(args[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                say(e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        } else if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("loginbot")) {
            if (sender.isOp()){
                toQ.bot.login();
                toQ.bot.getEventChannel().registerListenerHost(new ConMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
    }
}
```

ToQ Class:

```
package org.poem.qtoser;

import net.mamoe.mirai.*;
import net.mamoe.mirai.utils.BotConfiguration;

public class ToQ {
    public Bot bot;
    public ToQ(){
        bot = BotFactory.INSTANCE.newBot(**********,"**********",new BotConfiguration() {{
            setProtocol(MiraiProtocol.ANDROID_PHONE);
            fileBasedDeviceInfo();
        }});
    }
}
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: QToSer
version: '${project.version}'
main: org.poem.qtoser.QToSer
api-version: 1.19
commands:
  send:
    description: 向机器人发送消息.
    usage: /send [message]
```

I tried code transfers that would result in not being enabled, but you know, it didn't work. Because he reported an error when loading from the startup server, I had no clue at all.

Comment: You've noticed the underlying cause? `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes`

Comment: Always look for the "caused by..." line. It's not indented for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Add excludes to the pom.xml:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
</excludes>
```